# Piezoelectric driver capable of ~2500hz and 160-200 Vpp capable of driving a 30-50nF disk?

Tags: amplifier, piezo

I've been lucky enough to inherit a project where I need to be able to drive 35mm piezoelectric disk at a frequency of 2450 hz and an amplitude of 160 volts peak to peak. The last person on the team ordered a few DRV2667 and 2667 Eval boards, they did a lot of questionable things with this project, but just a glance at the datasheet I can see with the load it would only be capable of the ~80 Vpp it's producing with the circuit they built. Right now I have a sparkFun MiniGen as my waveform generator that produces 2.9 Vpp. I was hoping someone more experienced in the piezo space might have some ideas, I've looked around for a capable driver but haven't found anything so far.

I'm also open to any new ideas on how to get to my goal. For context, the project is building a self-contained circuit to run synthetic jet actuators to fit in the wings of an RC plane. Right now I'm using a 3.7V lipo to power the whole thing but the plane has a larger 12v lipo I could tap into if another driver that's 12v works.

Thanks

Comment: You can try to drive piezo with step-up transformer with inductance so together with piezo forms a 2450hz sine. (Parallel LC circuit)

Comment: Device DRV2667 can drive 200 Vpp ... at 300 or "500" Hz ... but at 2450  Hz?